# Deploying several copies of an MDB

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

We have a JMS topic that is receiving several types of messages(number of types is determined at deploy time) with a requirement that the messages are processed in order by type. All of the types can be handled by the same MDB.

We have a solution where we deploy several versions of that MDB with selectors for each type. While that works, it means that we need to update deployment descriptors in our application every time we deploy a new version which seems to be an error prone process.

We've considered using deployment plans to handle that, but from what I understand it's only possible to change existing MDBs, not add new ones.

Is there anything we are missing?

We are using weblogic 10.3

Comment: if the same mdb can handle all the types, why do you deploy with a selector per-type?  and, how do you ensure that the types are processed in order?

Comment: We are trying to improve throughput. The types don't need to be processed in order, only messages within a type.

Comment: so you have a single-mdb pool per type?

Comment: Basically, here is how we are expecting it to work and how it appears to work: messages are received by a topic and delivered to each MDB instance in FIFO order. Each MDB instance handles its messages and ignores messages with different selectors leading to messages being handled in order by type, but with different types not interfering with each other.

Comment: Yes, single-mdb pool per type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could handle it.  Since you are effectively single-threading the handling of messages of a given type, you could ditch your MDBs and instead manage a pool of threads, each handling a single type.  you could implement a singleton service which exposes a JMX management interface (or a remote EJB interface) which allows you to dynamically add/remove types.  when this service receives a call to add a new type, it starts a new thread which just loops doing a normal JMS receive call (with the appropriate selector).  if your service maintains a map of type -> thread, you could also implement logic for removing a type (e.g. interrupting the thread or otherwise informing it that it is finished).

if you get to the point where a type per thread no longer scales, then you would need to implement a more complex queuing and pooling solution in your service.

Comment: I am not sure if I am too fond of the idea of manually managing a thread pool, but it should work. I'll play around and see what I get.

Comment: @PavelRozenblioum - i agree, but i don't really see a better option if you want to be able to add types without redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Turn your topic into a queue. Create a "distributor" MDB of which you configure one (1) that listens on that queue.
That MDB accepts messages, maintains a (dynamic, static) map of type ("xyz") to queue ("queue15"), and re-sends the message to the appropriate "worker queue".
Create N (fixed, N > number of types) worker queues, with one of your MDBs listening on each queue. No special config required, since your MDB can handle any type.

This way, you do not need to know up-front just which message types there are.
Your worker MDBs will find that they receive only messages of one type, and in order.
Does that scale? Well, there is only one "distributor", but that just looks at the type, and re-sends. That should really be fast. The actual work is asynchronous on a second level.

I think it should even be possible to create "worker queues" dynamically, with the MDB to listen on them (probably via container-specific APIs?).

Comment: this only works if you know ahead of time the maximum number of types you have.  since the OP stated they wanted to be able to add types on the fly, how would you ever know what the max is?

Comment: @jtahlborn that's true, it would be an estimate. But still way better than to change DDs for every new type. Assume you have 100 types today, then just configure 200 queues. Agreed, you would need to re-configure again if now really see your types count approaching 200. But that may buy you some time.